# msi Notebook with Windows 8.1, can't start or boot

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, windows-installer

I changed my boot security settings from UEFI something to 'Legacy'
And now my PC can't start at all.

Every time I try I get:

```
Intel UNDI , PXE-2.0(Build 083)
Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation
For Qualcomm Atheros PCIE Ethernet Controller v2.1.1.5(03/15/13)
Check cable connection!
PXE-MOF : Exiting Intel PXE ROM
```

I have tried everything at start up to get back into the boot menu or just to get into anything. The only things I can get into is by pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> and then I get (after entering my security password):

```
Please select boot device:
PO: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GTAON
P4: WDC WD7500BPKX-22HPJTO
Qualcomm Atheros Boot
```

Pressing any of them I get back to "Intel UNDI , PXE-2.0.. ..."

Do any of you know a way to get back into the boot menu, cause besides me changing a setting nothing else was wrong with this PC?

My PC is:

```
MSI GP60 2PE-850NE Leopard, with Intel® Core™ i7 Processor
NVIDIA GeForce 840M 2GB VRAM DDR3 Windows 8.1
```

http://www.msi.com/product/nb/GP60-2pE-Leopard.html#hero-overview

Answer (score 1):

Today we have two Pre-OS environments: `UEFI` and `Legacy`.

UEFI mode is able to deal with GPT based HDDs while Legacy is not.
Then if your PC has a GPT HDD with the bootable OS on it and you changed to Legacy mode your PC will not be able to see an OS to boot from and it will default trying to boot from the network (PXE).

To solve your problem you must be able to invoke your `pre-boot environment user interface` at boot and switch back to UEFI mode. i.e. in HP PCs you must press [ESC] while booting to invoke a menu that allows selecting UEFI or Legacy.

Answer (score 1):

I know that's not very useful for you (a month later) but it may help someone else.

The MSI laptops have a "hot key recovery function", F3. So if pressed while restarting (when it displays the MSI screen) it takes you to a "choose an option" screen where you can "refresh" or "reset" your PC at "troubleshoot" options.

I hope this helps somebody!